# Retaining the screen-size of a polygon when zooming

Tags: javascript, gis, bing-maps

I have a function that plots a polygon centered over a certain location. I noticed that when a user zooms, the size of the polygon stays **geographically** the same, meaning it changes **screenwise** (i.e. zooming out displays a larger portion of the map, while the polygon occupies a small portion of the map).

One could say that I **position** the polygon with respect to **geographical** measurements but I wish to **size** it with respect to **screen** ditto.

How can I do that?

I suppose I could find out the size of the viewer or screen and check that against boundaries of the map and so on. However, that sounds like a tedious approach and I trust that there's functionality in the API that does all that for me, likely much faster and more reliably.

Comment: Since polygons are tied to locations you will need to just draw an image on the screen instead.

Comment: @Bryant I feared it was like that. So, basically, the last paragraph of my question **is** the way to go. Please post your comment as a reply so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since polygons are tied to locations you will need to just draw an image on the screen instead. (Unless you like to inflict pain upon yourself and recalculate all the polygon locations when the zoom changes).